# Angular directive default to checked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-directive

I have a directive (element) that I created for a "switch", that uses input[checkbox].

As long as the initial state of the checkbox is to be NOT checked, everything works fine. But if I want to set the initial state to checked (based on my controller value), then it's always the opposite. Why is the value not checked when the controller variable says it should be?

Html

```
<a-switch toggle-state="vm.doSomething"></a-switch>
```

Directive Html

```
<div class="switch-container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
    <label for="switch" class="pm-switch"></label>
</div>
```

Javascript controller

```
vm.doSomething = {
    state: true
};
```

Directive

```
angular.module('material')
    .directive('aSwitch', [
        '$timeout', function($timeout) {
            return {
                templateUrl: 'elements/material/switch/switch.html',
                transclude: false,
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    toggleState: '=',
                },
                link: function (scope, element) {
                    element.on('click touchstart', function (event) {
                        if (event.srcElement && event.srcElement.id && event.srcElement.id === "switch") {
                            event.stopPropagation();

                            $timeout(function() {
                                scope.toggleState.state = !scope.toggleState.state;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    ]);
```

I realize that in order to set the checked state of a generic

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

I just need to add the attribute "checked", like

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

but how do I do that if it's inside my directive's html?

Comment: you could fix this by doing `<input type="checkbox" id="switch" ng-model="toggleState.state"/>` & then timeout function would be `                            `$timeout(function() {
                                scope.toggleState.state = scope.toggleState.state? scope.toggleState.state: false;
                            });`

Comment: wow, using this approach negated the need for the "link" section in my directive, please add this as an answer so I can give you points

Comment: cool I'll do it in an hour..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using isolated scope which has `scope: { toggleState: '='}` in it, you should have directly bind that `toggleState.state` to the input box inside template, so that the link function code will get remove as `toggleState` has been two way binded with your controller scope variable using `toggle-state` attribute

**Directive.html**

```
<div class="switch-container">
    <input type="checkbox" id="switch" ng-model="toggleState.state"/>
    <label for="switch" class="pm-switch"></label>
</div>
```